# unable to delete some files in build/web/WEB-INF/lib

Tags: netbeans

How do I resolve this issue in Netbeans?

```
Warning: unable to delete some files in build/web/WEB-INF/lib - they are probably locked by the J2EE server.
```

Ted

Answer (score 0):

I use [unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) on the locked files to find out which process is locking them. Then, I kill those hanging processes if I can't stop them within NetBeans or on the App/Web server.